# How to detect when send_data from rails server updates the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, proxy

I'm trying to build a simple proxy server with ruby on rails. Here's what I want to do:
1. Receive a link from browser request
2. Fetch content from that link
3. Return the result to the user via send_data
4. The send_data triggers an event in the browser and the browser does something else with the received content.

The parts until #3 are easy, but I can't seem to find a way to do #4: make the browser detect a send_data event from my server. Anyone know how to do this? Or is this even possible?